# Show that any closed disk in $\mathbb{R²}$ containing a limited semi-orbit of $x' = f(x)$ necessarily contains one equilibrium point.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that any closed disk in $\mathbb{R²}$ containing a limited semi-orbit of $x' = f(x)$ necessarily contains one equilibrium point.

Sorry for the mistakes in the translation, I am Brazilian and thanks for the help.